# Maximum likelihood estimation for beta distribution

Tags: optimization, maximum-likelihood, hessian-matrix

I am trying to fit a beta distribution  to my data using MLE. I calculated the log likelihood function for beta distribution.
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
LL(\alpha,\beta) = (\alpha-1)n\bar{\ln x_i}+(\beta-1)n\bar{\ln (1-x_i)}+n\ln \Gamma(\alpha+\beta)-n \ln \Gamma(\alpha)-n \ln \Gamma(\beta) 
\end{equation}
We can ignore $n$ as it is just a scaling factor. In my case values for $\bar{\ln x_i}$ and $\bar{\ln (1-x_i)}$ are -2.62 and -0.15 respectively. So when I plot log likelihood function against the parameter space of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the function looks concave with a peak around 1 for $\alpha$ and around 5 for $\beta$. So based on these observations, I would conclude that my function is concave for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ around these values.

[image: Counter plot of log likelihood function]

[image: Counter plot of log likelihood function (zoomed in)]

So far so good. These values also match from what I get by finding the maximum of log likelihood function numerically. But when I calculate the Hessian of this function:

$\begin{bmatrix}
\psi_1(\alpha+\beta)-\psi_1(\alpha) & \psi_1(\alpha+\beta)\\
\psi_1(\alpha+\beta) & \psi_1(\alpha+\beta)-\psi_1(\beta) 
\end{bmatrix}$

where
$\psi_1$ is the polygamma function of order 1. It doesn't look like this maxtrix is negative semidefinite. Do you think I am missing something?

Thank you